# Examples of sets for which the Zorn's lemma is applicable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Zorn' Lemma: Let $M\neq \emptyset$ be a partially ordered set. Suppose that every chain (totally ordered set) has an upper bound. Then $M$ has at least one maximal element.

Example 1: Let $M$ be the set of real numbers that belong to the interval $[0,1)\cup[2,3)$ and the ordering relation is usual for $\mathbb{R}$. It's a totally ordered set and it has an upper bound $3$. How is it possible that $M$ has a maximal element since it is an open set?

Example 2: Let $M=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $a\subset b$ and $c\subset d$, the ordering relation is inclusion. It's a partially ordered set. The chain $\{a,b\}$ has an upper bound $b$, the chain $\{c,d\}$ has an upper bound $d$. What is the maximal element of $M:$ $\{a,b,c,d\}$, $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ or both? Why so?

Than you for your help!

Comment: Neither $\{a,b,c,d\}$ nor $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ are maximal elements of $M$. Indeed, neither of them are elements of $M$ at all: both are subsets, which the conclusion of Zorn's lemma says nothing about.

Comment: @Eric Stucky Thank you for the reply! What would be the maximal element? $b$ and $d$ aren't related.

Comment: As lockjaw says in their answer, "*the lemma doesn't stop us from having more than one maximal element*".

Comment: @Eric Stucky, so the correct answer is both $b$ and $d$?

Comment: Perhaps a good start is to review the definition of partial order, and maximal element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemma requires that the upper bound corresponding to a chain have an upper bound ***in*** $M$.

For your first example, there is no upper bound for the totally ordered set $[2,3)$ in $M$.

Please note that for your second example the lemma doesn't stop us from having more than one maximal element -- it just ensures that one exists.

Comment: @ G. Sassatelli: Per your edit to the OP's question, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Not my edit. I just edited tags.